# build docker image with circleci/php:7.3-cli-node-browsers

Tags: php, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build an image in docker but after it compiles, I execute docker-compose up and it exits.

The docker file that I am using contains the next instructions:

```
FROM circleci/php:7.3-cli-node-browsers 

USER root

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libpng-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        zip \
        curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && apt-get install -y zip \
    && apt-get install -y unzip \
    && apt-get install -y git \  
    && apt install -y libsqlite3-dev zlib1g-dev \ 
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath && docker-php-ext-enable bcmath \
    && docker-php-ext-install pcntl \
    && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libmagickwand-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install exif \
    && pecl install imagick \
    && docker-php-ext-enable imagick

RUN pecl install redis && docker-php-ext-enable redis

COPY .docker/vhost.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

WORKDIR /var/www/html
COPY / /var/www/html

RUN composer self-update
RUN composer install -n --prefer-dist

RUN npm install

RUN npm run test 

RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www/html
RUN chmod -R o+w /var/www/html/storage

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

This a laravel project, with node and Redis. Any ideas why it is not working?

Thank in advance for your help.

Comment: What's in the container logs when you run it?  What's in the `docker-entrypoint.sh` script?

Comment: @DavidMaze docker-entrypoint.sh :   #!/bin/sh
env >> /etc/environment
echo "--> Running Node"
#npm run prod
echo "--> Running Artisan cache clear"
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan storage:link
echo "--> Starting app"
# exec apache2 -D FOREGROUND
exec apache2-foreground
"$@"

Comment: Even if I delete the lines for the .sh, it doesn't run

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I already solved it, using a different image that has Apache included. That was the issue (apache missing)

Answer (score 0):

Your entrypoint finally call `apache`, but you even did not install apache in your docker image.

So, you need do next:

- Install apache2 in `Dockerfile`:

  ```
  RUN apt-get install -y apache2
  ```
- Correctly launch apache2 in `docker-entrypoint.sh`:

  ```
  echo "--> Starting app"
  . /etc/apache2/envvars
  mkdir -p /var/run/apache2
  exec apache2 -D FOREGROUND
  ```

Comment: I am getting the next error while building the image:                                                      
 #22 [18/18] RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat
#22 0.261 ln: failed to create symbolic link '/docker-entrypoint.sh': File exists
#22 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat]: exit code: 1
------
 > [18/18] RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat:
------

Comment: What changes compared to original question? You mentioned you have finished building before ... You mention issue comes from container run when do docker-compose up, could you clarify first？

Comment: It builds without the  docker-entrypoint.sh commands. This line RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat is the one that is giving me the issue. @atline

Comment: I had a look for your image, there is already a `docker-entrypoint.sh` in `circleci/php:7.3-cli-node-browsers` with the content `#!/bin/sh
Xvfb :99 -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
exec "$@"
`...... So, why you need this `ln -s`? I don't think it's useful.

Comment: Or if you insist, you could add `RUN rm -f /docker-entrypoint.sh` before that command. Still I think you no need to do that symbol link.

Comment: So you suggest I should delete the line (RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh / # backwards compat) from my docker-compose? If so, the rest stays the same?

Comment: You could verify your function after delete

Comment: Getting this error : AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using IP. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message.

Comment: And when I check in the browser it shows the code of the main page

Comment: This is warning not errors. You already make it work

Comment: Right, but I can see the code of the application. I mean, I see the whole code of the index page. Something is missing. And there is nothing wrong with the code of the application.